# Is it possible to save DHCP reservations to disk so they can be restored after rebooting Linksys AX5400 router

Tags: dhcp, static-ip

I'm not a network administrator, but I play one at home. I have this Linksys AX5400 router on which I have configured some DHCP reserved addresses. When I need to reboot the router, I would like to be able to restore these settings from disk. Is there any way to backup and restore these settings with a command? My main PC runs Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: But even for a consumer product I would expect DHCP reservations to be kept during restarts. I'd contact Linksys support about this.

Comment: I should say that my googling was for DHCP reservation on the Linksys router. There is much to be found on DHCP reservation, but it's mostly about a DHCP server, not a router.

Comment: A silent downvote for off topic content is not something I'd consider insulting. It's merely an indication that it's off topic.

Comment: @SteveCohen it can be insulting. There’s a process for off-topic questions.

Comment: Yes. When I originally posted I was unaware of the limited mandate of this group. Later, I got something telling me a better place to post. A comment to that effect would have avoided all the rancor. The original -1 listed all sorts of other possible reasons including lack of research, which I regarded as insulting. Really, a comment instead of a -1 or in addition to a -1 would be more polite and useful. Or a banner headline saying don’t post here if you’re not a corporate sysadmin. A bare -1 signals “beneath contempt”. That’s my opinion, anyway. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a backup/restore option on the Admin page of the router that I missed. Neither the documentation nor tech support mentioned this.

Sorry for bothering the group.

Comment: Take care to avoid restoring a config after a firmware update. Weird things can happen

Comment: Thanks for the warning.